# referencing to MEDIA_ROOT without hardcoding local directory

Tags: django, url, media

How do I change MEDIA_ROOT so its not a hardcoded directory value?

settings.py

```
    MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
    MEDIA_ROOT = '/Users/blah/djangoproj/abc/abc/media/static/'
```

.py file

```
from django.conf import settings
print settings.MEDIA_ROOT
```

urls.py

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.conf import settings

urls = (...
(r'^%s(?P<path>.*)$'%settings.MEDIA_URL, 'django.views.static.serve', {
        'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

This should allow you to move your project easily between folders:

if your path is /home/user/projects/app/static/media/

```
SITE_ROOT = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'static/media')
```